# How to retrieve the column name and row name with a condition satisfied in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to check a condition if the sum of columns is 1 and if satisfies i want to retrieve the column names and row number in a dictionary.
[image]

The output should be `list1=({8:1004},{9:1001})`.

I have tried some python code but couldn't move forward  with the code.

```
list1=[]
for Emp in SkillsA:
        sum_row = (SkillsA.sum(axis=0))
#print(sum_row)
        # print((Skills_A[0]))
        if sum_row[Emp] == 1:
            #print(Emp)
            for ws in SkillsA:
#                if SkillsA[ws][Emp] == 1:
                    print(SkillsA[ws][Emp])
                    #list1.update({Emp:ws})
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Are you familiar with Pandas? Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0):

With Pandas you can do it

```
import pandas as pd

#   Import data
df = pd.read_excel("location_file")

#   Create a dictionary
dict = dict()

#   Iterate in columns
for i in df.columns:
        if df[i].sum() == 1:   
            dict[i] = df.Employee_No[df[i] == 1] # Add filter data to dict
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on describing the problem as

*Find a mapping of columns labels to row labels for the 1s in columns having only a single 1*,

it can also be done with a one-line function:

```
def indices_of_single_ones_by_column(df):
    return [{col: df[col].idxmax()} for col in df.columns if df[col].sum() == 1]
```